# Angular2: Reference form in the html from outside of the form tag

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to do the following :

```
<span *ngIf="heroForm?.dirty">
    FOO
</span>
<form *ngIf="active" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #heroForm="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"
        required
        [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="name"
        #name="ngModel">
    </div>
</form>
```

Basically, displaying a span outside of the form tag, using the form states (here `dirty`). Unfortunately, `FOO` is never shown. Is there any way to work around this ?

Comment: i don't know if it possible in template driven forms, but the behaviour you want can be easily achieved in model driven forms :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a model property, `showFoo: boolean`

and change that on some form event, like onChange

then your `span` will look like

`<span *ngIf="showFoo">FOO</span>`